# Uncaught ReferenceError: function_name is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have added `jquery.min` and `myJavascript` javascript files respectively. `myJavascript` contains the following function:

```
function delete_selected(){  
    // ...  
}
```

From my HTML file I am calling this function:

```
<a class="btn default btn-xs red-sunglo" onclick="delete_selected();"> 
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

It is working fine in Firefox, but giving the following error in Chrome:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: delete_selected is not defined

Comment: Are there any other console errors in Chrome?

Comment: I am getting following error too in myJavascript.js file."Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Comment: That's your problem. Fix that one and your code should work.

Comment: This is the line: function readURL(input, type=null) { ...

Comment: It would help more if you edited your question to include the whole function, but remove the `= null` from that line. Javascript cannot define default values in the function signature in the same method that C# etc can.

Comment: I made a simple test and it seems to not work for me too. Maybe it has something to do with this : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution

Comment: i removed = null. now it is working. Thank you very much Rory McCrossan :)